# Missing required parameters for Route after razorpay response in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, razorpay

I try to redirect to some `route:url` to capture my payment, and I have to passed the `payment_id` and `amount` to capture from controller, but the routes gives error like below

Thanks in advance

Errors I got

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
  Missing required parameters for [Route: razorpay.standard.success] [URI: razorpay/standard/success/{rzpId}/{amount}]. (View: /home/valpuia/projects/bagisto/packages/Vaube/Razorpay/src/Resources/views/standard-redirect.blade.php)
```

My Route

```
Route::prefix('razorpay/standard')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/success/{rzpId}/{amount}', 'RazorPayController@success')->name('razorpay.standard.success');
}
```

Controller

```
public function success($rzpId, $amt)
{
    dd($rzpId);
}
```

Blade.php `after razorpay completed`

```
"handler": function (response){
            // alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
            if (typeof response.razorpay_payment_id == 'undefined' || response.razorpay_payment_id < 1) {
                redirect_url = '{{ route('razorpay.standard.cancel') }}';
            } else {
                redirect_url = '{{ route('razorpay.standard.success', [ "rzp_id" => 'response.razorpay_payment_id', "amount" => '$total_amount * 100']) }}';
            }
            location.href = redirect_url;
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the javascript variables inside PHP

try this solution:

```
Route::prefix('razorpay/standard')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/success/{rzpId?}/{amount?}', 'RazorPayController@success')->name('razorpay.standard.success');
}
```

and then change the route to

```
"handler": function (response){
            // alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
            if (typeof response.razorpay_payment_id == 'undefined' || response.razorpay_payment_id < 1) {
                redirect_url = '{{ route('razorpay.standard.cancel') }}';
            } else {
                redirect_url = '{{ route("razorpay.standard.success")}}/'+response.razorpay_payment_id+'/'+'{{$total_amount * 100}}';
            }
            location.href = redirect_url;
        },
```

Comment: yayy.... its working, but why `{rzpId?}`  add `question mark`? can you explain

Comment: because first you need to use the route without any parameters

Comment: {{ route("razorpay.standard.success")}}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in parameter name.

Please replace

`"rzp_id" => 'response.razorpay_payment_id'`

with

`"rzpId" => 'response.razorpay_payment_id'`

and try

Comment: still not working, also I try `redirect_url = '{{ route('razorpay.standard.success', [ "rzpId" => ' + response.razorpay_payment_id + ', "amount" => ' . $total_amount * 100 . ']) }}';` to concatenate, but still not working